# How to execute a local python script into a docker from another python script?

Tags: python, docker, external-script

Let me clarify what I want to do.

I have a python script in my local machine that performs a lot of stuff and in certain point it have to call another python script that must be executed into a docker container. Such script have some input arguments and it returns some results.

So i want to figure out how to do that.

Example:

```
def function()
    do stuff
         .
         .
         .
    do more stuff

    ''' call another local script that must be executed into a docker'''

    result = execute_python_script_into_a_docker(python script arguments)
```

The docker has been launched in a terminal as:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 my_docker
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add your file inside docker container thanks to `-v` option.

```sh
docker run -it -v myFile.py:/myFile.py -p 8888:8888 my_docker
```

And execute your python inside your docker with :
`py /myFile.py`

or with the host:

```sh
docker run -it -v myFile.py:/myFile.py -p 8888:8888 my_docker py /myFile.py
```

And even if your docker is already running

```sh
docker exec -ti docker_name py /myFile.py
```

`docker_name` is available after a `docker ps` command.

Or you can specify name in the run command like:

```sh
docker run -it --name docker_name -v myFile.py:/myFile.py -p 8888:8888 my_docker
```

---

It's like:

```
-v absoluteHostPath:absoluteRemotePath
```

You can specify folder too in the same way:

```
-v myFolder:/customPath/myFolder
```

More details at [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/).

Comment: Yes i'm aware that i can do that, but the question here is how can i do it from another local python script, i'm not able to figure out how do that, I mean the script_1 must run in local machine, and then in certain point of the rutine it must call the other script (script_2) in the docker...

Comment: You have to execute from shell. Try to launch your command in shell with python : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Answer (score 3):

You can use docker's [python SDK library](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). First you need to move your script there, I recommend you do it when you create the container or when you start it as Callmemath mentioned:

```py
docker run -it -v myFile.py:/myFile.py -p 8888:8888 my_docker
```

Then to run the script using the library:

```py
...
client = docker.client.from_env()
container = client.containers.get(CONTAINER_ID)
exit_code, output = container.exec_run("python your_script.py script_args")
...
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `docker exec  -it image_name python /filename`

Note: To use 'docker exec' you must run the container using `docker run`

Comment: how do we keep it running?

Comment: @NikhilVJ When running docker from terminal you can add the flag -d to detach the execution of docker from terminal, then you can use the same terminal to execute the command docker exec... or use another terminal